# Executing Multiple ML Models simultaneously on multiple cores to reduce the model building time

Tags: machine-learning, sequence-modeling, forecasting

I have a time series forecasting problem which consist of date, item no and quantity columns. I have defined a function which takes input as data frame and forecasting period (Daily,Weekly,Monthly,Yearly) and in that function I have a for loop which runs according to the item no. in which 8-10 ML models are trained on each item no and its relevant data. There are like 40 item nos. for each item no. a pickle file is generated and all the accuracies are compared and best of all is selected for that item no. The normal approach is taking more than 3 days to train the models. I want train the models concurrently and save the pickle file.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @foreverska I want to reduce the time to train the model... can we train models at processor core level simultaneously. If it takes 15 mins to train one model and 1 hr to train four models. can we train four models on one core each and make it done in 15 mins simultaneously